# GLSL calculating normal on a sphere mesh in vertex shader using noise function by sampling is producing strange graphical errors

Tags: opengl, glsl, noise, vertex-shader, normals

I'm trying to calculate the normals on surface of a sphere in the vertex shader because I defer my noise calculation to the vertex shader. The normal results are good when my theta (sampling angle) is closer to 1 but for more detailed terrain & a smaller theta my normals become very incorrect. Here's what I mean:

*Accurate normals*

[image: Accurate normals]

*More detailed noise with a higher theta*

[image: More detailed noise with a higher theta]

*Zoomed in onto surface of last image. Red indicates ridges, blue indicates incorrect shadows*

[image: More detailed noise with a higher theta zoomed in]

The code I use to calculate normals is:

```
vec3 calcNormal(vec3 pos)
{
    float theta = .1; //The closer this is to zero the less accurate it gets
    vec3 vecTangent = normalize(cross(pos, vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        + cross(pos, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
    vec3 vecBitangent = normalize(cross(vecTangent, pos));
    vec3 ptTangentSample = getPos(pos + theta * normalize(vecTangent));
    vec3 ptBitangentSample = getPos(pos + theta * normalize(vecBitangent));

    return normalize(cross(ptTangentSample - pos, ptBitangentSample - pos));
}
```

I call calcNormal with

```
calcNormal(getPos(position))
```

where getPos is the 3D noise function that takes and returns a vec3 and position is the original position on the sphere.

Comment: Should you maybe normalize the arguments of `getPos()` to project it back on the sphere? Is it correct to assume that the sphere has unit radius and is centered at the origin?

Comment: @NicoSchertler OH! That's right. Thanks!
I changed the ptTangentSample and ptBitangentSample lines to getPos( **normalize** (...))

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @NicoSchertler the correct version of calcNormal is

```
vec3 calcNormal(vec3 pos)
{
    float theta = .00001; 
    vec3 vecTangent = normalize(cross(pos, vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
     + cross(pos, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
    vec3 vecBitangent = normalize(cross(vecTangent, pos));
    vec3 ptTangentSample = getPos(normalize(pos + theta * normalize(vecTangent)));
    vec3 ptBitangentSample = getPos(normalize(pos + theta * normalize(vecBitangent)));

     return normalize(cross(ptTangentSample - pos, ptBitangentSample - pos));
  }
```